# Movement of $1/z$ in complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, circles, inverse

How is moving $\frac{1}{z}$ in complex plane if $z$ is described by a circle which has radius $r$ and center $a+b*i$

I've just started complex algebra and still having some trouble imagining it.
How one does even solve this kind of problems, I don't want the complete solution I just want some appropriate ways for working with complex numbers to solve this kind of problems. 
Thank you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=a+bi$. Then the points $z$ of your circle are characterized by $|z-c|=r$. This translates to
$$
(z-c)(\bar{z}-\bar{c})=r^2
$$
You want to find $w=1/z$, so you can substitute $z=1/w$:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{w}-c\right)\left(\frac{1}{\bar{w}}-\bar{c}\right)=r^2
$$
and, doing the simplifications,
$$
(|c|^2-r^2)w\bar{w}-\bar{c}w-c\bar{w}+1=0
$$
Now write $w=x+iy$: then $\bar{c}w=(a-ib)(x+iy)=ax-ibx+aiy+by$ and $c\bar{w}=ax+ibx-aiy+by$, so the equation becomes
$$
(|c|^2-r^2)(x^2+y^2)-2ax-2by+1=0
$$
Can you recognize this locus?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Compute $\dfrac1{r\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr)}$.

Comment: $ θ = arctan(b/a)  $ but how am I going to draw anything using this?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply it by $z^*/z^*$, where $z = r[\cos\theta + i \sin\theta]$ and $z^* = r[\cos\theta - i \sin\theta]$, that should get you

$$
\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{z}\frac{z^*}{z^*} = \frac{z^*}{|z|^2} = \frac{r[\cos\theta - i \sin\theta]}{r^2} = \frac{1}{r}[\cos\theta - i\sin\theta]
$$
and
$$
\theta = arctan(b/a)
$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: I think I can. thank you.

Comment: This assumes the center of the circle is $0$.

Comment: Then how would the general case be? This confused me already(

Comment: @R0xx0rZzz  Let $w=a+b i$. Given $(z-w)\left(\bar{z}-\bar{w}\right)=r^2$, put $u=1/z$. We get $(1-u w)\left(1-\bar{u} \bar{w}\right)=r^2u \bar{u}$. Complete the square. If $|w|\neq  r$ we get a circle, otherwise a straight line